# return true for click event and continue

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I have a popup window control what I'm trying todo is get it to continue the click event if the user chooses the yes button. How do you continue the click event for the 'yes' button, I'm trying to make it return true but it doesn't continue for the click it just return false.

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.delete-question').click(function(e) {                   
            ret = false;    
            _this = this;

            $('#pop-up-1').popUpWindow({
                modal: true,
                blurClass: '.main-container',
                action: "open",
                buttons: [{
                    text: "Yes",
                    click: function () {

                        this.close();
                        ret = true;
                    }
                }, {
                    text: "No",
                    click: function () {
                        this.close();                                   
                    }
                }]
            }); 

            return ret;
        })  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: Short answer is that you can't. The `return` will always be done before the user can click any of the popup's buttons. For more info, [Why is my variable unaltered after I modify it inside of a function?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23667086/why-is-my-variable-unaltered-after-i-modify-it-inside-of-a-function-asynchron) and [How to return the response from an asynchronous call?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/14220321/how-to-return-the-response-from-an-asynchronous-call)

Comment: What plugin are you using for modal window?

Comment: I've altered a plugin which I downloaded a while back, I'm really stack can someone help me out please as what todo

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't do it directly, but you can emit the `click` event once it is needed, e.g. something like this (not tested):

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 
    // global flag to track the popup state
    var popupReturn = false;

    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('.delete-question').click(function(e) {
            // when true (after Yes click only) go on returning true
            if (popupReturn) {
                popupReturn = false;
                return true;
            }
            else {
              _this = this;

              $('#pop-up-1').popUpWindow({
                  modal: true,
                  blurClass: '.main-container',
                  action: "open",
                  buttons: [{
                      text: "Yes",
                      click: function () {
                          // set global flag to true
                          popupReturn = true;
                          // emit click event where it knows that popupReturn is true
                          $(_this).click();
                          this.close();
                      }
                  }, {
                      text: "No",
                      click: function () {
                          this.close();                                   
                      }
                  }]
                });
                return false;
            }
        })  
    });
</script>
```

Comment: When I click the .delete question button it just fires the click event without the modal popup showing

Comment: Yeah I tried you code it has no errors but the click event for .delete-question isn't getting fired

Answer (score 2):

You can't return from asynchronous event like in your case, because your "modal" is not really modal in sense that it doesn't pause code execution until use clicks a button.

This is where callback come handy. I would wrap the modal code into helper plugin and use it like this:

```
$.fn.confirmable = function(options) {

    options = $.extend({
        close: $.noop,
        dismiss: $.noop
    }, options);

    this.each(function() {
        $(this).popUpWindow({
            modal: true,
            blurClass: '.main-container',
            action: "open",
            buttons: [{
                text: "Yes",
                click: function() {
                    this.close();
                    options.close();
                }
            }, {
                text: "No",
                click: function() {
                    this.close();
                    options.dismiss();
                }
            }]
        });
    });
};


$('.delete-question').confirmable({
    close: function() {
        // ok pressed do something
    },
    dismiss: function() {
        // cancel pressed
    }
});
```

It means that your workflow needs to transform to asynchronous callback/promise-based.